# Starting a Google Compute instance with Python

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I am trying to start a Google Compute instance with the Google API Python Client Library. This is so that a cheap instance (running on a single core) can periodically start and stop a more expensive instance (with many cores) periodically, to keep costs down.

I have successfully installed the different components and run Google's example script [create_instance.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py) (which creates an instances, runs a startup script, and deletes the instance). Inspecting the PyDoc reference for the Compute Engine API, and cross-referencing how the other instances() functions work in the create_instance.py example, I would expect the start instance command to be:

```
python compute.instances().start(project=*, zone=*, instance=*).execute()
```

The above command gives me the error "An expression was expected after '('. at line:1 char:34" - this is the first parenthesis.

a. What have I done wrong?

b. Is using the Google API with Python a good way to start instances from other instances, programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generally I would expect you would need to import the api library with an `import` statement or perhaps a runtime flag (`-m somemodule`?).  Running a line of python directly from the command line is usually not the best way to proceed. Instead Google provides the [`gcloud` command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/).
2. An authentication/login function is usually called before sending the API actual commands.  On a Google VM, this can be either an id/private key or a blank id/key if the VM is specifically authorized to call the API or act as a specific account. This authorization can be set up from the compute engine web control panel when creating a Google VM the first time. On an external VM, it will need an id/private key to supply to the Google API.  So, a one liner in python probably won't work as it is missing this step.
3. The `compute.instances().start()` function takes **required** parameters to start a specific instance that has stopped.  That means:

   - the VM instance has been created previously
   - the VM instance is in the stopped state
   - the instance to be restarted is identified by a specific project id, a (geo) zone, and an instance name that is supplied in the call to `start`

From [Google Cloud Python Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html#start)

> start(project=*, zone=*, instance=*) Starts an instance that was
>   stopped  using the instances().stop method. For more
>   information, see Restart an instance.
>
> Args:   project: string, Project ID for this request. (required)
>   zone: string, The name of the zone for this request. (required)
>   instance: string, Name of the instance resource to start. (required)
>
> ...

Comment: You're right. Gcloud is much easier. As to your second comment, all the VM exists, it is in a stopped state, and I have filled out the * in the start command (I just didn't make them public here)...

Comment: @fifthace I don't recall what to import or call to login to the Google Compute API from python, but expect it works similarly to earlier experience with nodejs.  See my edit to #2

Answer (score 5):

Below is the code needed to start a compute engine instance

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
print('VM Instance starting')

# Project ID for this request.
project = 'project_name' 

# The name of the zone for this request.
zone = 'zone_value'  

# Name of the instance resource to start.
instance = 'instance_name'

request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
response = request.execute()

print('VM Instance started')
```

This is the code I used for starting my VM instance from a cloud function.

An important thing to note here is that this can only start an instance if the instance is in stopped state, which suits my requirements perfectly.

Comment: Can you provide a link or reference where you got this API code?

Comment: Is the code shown being called from App Engine? How would this work in a Google Cloud Function?

Comment: I am using this code in a cloud function to start an Compute Engine Instance, not app engine. Unfortunately I dont have the link for API reference but I can tell you that this is working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.cloud import compute_v1

project = ""
zone = ""
instance_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient.from_service_account_file("ServiceAccount.json")
instance_list = instance_client.list(project=project, zone=zone)
for instance in instance_list:
    print(instance.name)
    instance_client.start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance.name)
```

Requires iam role Compute Admin
Source available here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute

Answer (score -2):

I used the code shared by @user570778, and for me it worked fine.

`from googleapiclient import discovery

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
print('VM Instance starting')

## Project ID for this request.

project = 'project_name'

## The name of the zone for this request.

zone = 'zone_value'

## Name of the instance resource to start.

instance = 'instance_name'

request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
response = request.execute()

print('VM Instance started')
`
I'm wondering, is it possible to start multiples instance in the same function?

Comment: Please use code formatting to format code, because it makes the code easier to read